# Copy Defined range into next available column on another sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2003

Im trying to paste a nominated rage from one workbook to another, my nominated range is called SourceRange and its destination is TargetRange.

However, if data exists in the column c2 on my TargetRange workbook i need to paster the SourceRange into the next Available column in my TargetRange.

The code bellow currently copies the SourceRange in yellow if no data is present in c2 if there is data it makes it green, the green instance need to be pasted into the next available column after c2 so d2.

I know about the offset function but I am unsure of where I should use it.

```
 Select Case MasterWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("c2") = ""


Case True
' The opened file automatically becomes the new active workbook and active worksheet.

Set SourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("c2:c26")
Set TargetRange = MasterWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("c2:c29")
' Copy cell values one at a time from the source range to the target range.


For Row = 2 To 29
    TargetRange.Cells(Row, 1).Value = SourceRange.Cells(Row, 1).Value
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Close

' Set background colour of target range.
TargetRange.Select
With Selection.Interior
    .ColorIndex = 6
    .Pattern = xlSolid

End With

Case False

' The opened file automatically becomes the new active workbook and active worksheet.

Set SourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("c2:c26")
Set TargetRange = MasterWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("c2:c29")
' Copy cell values one at a time from the source range to the target range.

'Sheets.Add.Name = "workbookname"
For Row = 2 To 29
    TargetRange.Cells(Row, 1).Value = SourceRange.Cells(Row, 1).Value



Next

ActiveWorkbook.Close


' Set background colour of target range.
TargetRange.Select
With Selection.Interior
    .ColorIndex = 10
    .Pattern = xlSolid

End With
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub test()
     Dim SourceRange As Range
     Dim TargetRange As Range
     ' The opened file automatically becomes the new active workbook and active worksheet.

     Set SourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("c2:c26")
     Set TargetRange = MasterWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("b3")
     If TargetRange.Text <> "" then
         Set TargetRange = TargetRange.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
     End If
     Set TargetRange = MasterWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(TargetRange, TargetRange.Offset(25, 0))
     ' Copy cell values ALL AT ONCE from the source range to the target range.

     SourceRange.Copy
     TargetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

     ActiveWorkbook.Close

     ' Set background colour of target range.

     With TargetRange.Interior
         .ColorIndex = IIf(TargetRange.Column = 3, 6, 10)
         .Pattern = xlSolid
     End With
End Sub
```

I suggest you step through it line by line so you understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks I kinda got it working last night but with some issues, ill try your code and see what happens.

Comment: I seem to get an error setting TargetRange again: Set TargetRange = TargetRange.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) is not allowed "Application-defined, object-defined error" I can't see how as we have already set : Set TargetRange = MasterWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("b2")

Comment: Is there any data in cell b2? If not the command will be trying to set the range off the right side of the sheet. I will change the code.

Comment: If there is data in "b2" it needs to paste into the next available cell "c2" and so on.

The next time you add the data it goes into d2 then e2 then f2 e.c.t

Regards,